# Simple Rails 3 question: How to check if some product has a description?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Each `Product` has several fields, including `description` which is a string (if there is no description then `description=""`).

What is the easiest method to find out if there is at least one `Product` with non empty description ?

```
non_empty_description_exist = Product.<what should be here?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Product.all.any? { |product| product.description.present? }
```

Comment: It's way too dangerous form performance perspective. It'll populate ALL Proudct records in db, map them into objects and only than reject without description, which IMHO is huge overhead

Comment: I agree. Go with the answer c0r0ner provided.

Answer (score 3):

```
Product.count(:conditions => "description IS NOT NULL")
```

if null value is allowed. 
It'll return the total count of Products with description available.

If you need the first product with description per se, use first instead of count

Comment: This is much more peformant from a data access perspective. The accepted answer is fine if and only if the entire collection has already been loaded -- in which case the performance penalty lies elsewhere in the application.

Comment: Based on a model name Product, I have educated guess that the whole products collection shouldn't be ever loaded at once.